# PlayGoogle: Не удалось сохранить изменения. Повторите попытку

Tags: android, google-play

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такого рода ошибка возникла вчера при попытке опубликовать приложение в play.google.com, ранее не было замечено подобного, а 2 дня назад все публиковалось отлично. Пробовал во всех доступных браузерах, очищал кэши и куки, переустанавливал хром... В общем все как в рекомендациях прописано.

Я просто не понимаю причину возникновения данной неприятности, может кто подскажет что и к чему?) Заранее благодарю.

Comment: обратитесь в сп google

Comment: iFr0z - Спасибо за ответ. Написал, но ответа долго ждать(

Comment: зато эффективней

Comment: Нужно вылогиниться и залогиниться обратно. [решение проблемы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186917/apk-upload-failed?newreg=ea79125efdc44c4cbf24773e68e3b6c5)